# Redirect back to previous page after logged in (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have created login page forced login in several pages. Now i need to redirect back to previous page after successful login.

When i force login by `@login_required(login_url='/login/')`. It includes `next` parameter in query string.

[image]

I tried to catch it with `redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get('next', '')` and send it to redirect `return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)` but didn't work.

**view.py**

```
def login(request):
    def errorHandle(error):
        form = LoginForm()
        return render_to_response('login/login.html', {
            'error' : error,
            'form' : form,
            })
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = LoginForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get('next', '')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    # Redirect to a success page.
                    auth_login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
#                    return render_to_response('login/logged_in.html', {
#                        'username': username,
#                        })
                else:
                    # Return a 'disabled account' error message
                    error = u'Account Disabled'
                    return errorHandle(error)
            else:
            # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
                error = u'Invalid Login'
                return errorHandle(error)
        else:
            error = u'Form is Invalid'
            return errorHandle(error)
    else:
        form = LoginForm() # An unbound form
        return render_to_response('login/login.html', {
            'form': form,
            })
```

**template**

```
<div id="login_form">
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</div>
```

EDIT - I found the issue. It was problem with my template. This form below works fine.

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="username">User name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="button"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next|escape }}" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Why not to use built-in [login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) view? Why not to at least [look at its code](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L25) to see how it does redirection?

Comment: @DrTyrsa i don't know how to use built-in login :/ can you find issue with this code ?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) on auth? Is something unclear there?

Comment: @DrTyrsa where can i get /account/ files for auth ?

Comment: [Set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) [these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#login-url) [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#logout-url).

Comment: @DrTyrsa i was trying to use default auth views. added  `url(r'^login/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login')` to `urls.py` but it says `TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/ registration/login.html`. Do i have to create login.html template manually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add this to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{% if request.REQUEST.next %}{{ request.REQUEST.next }}{% else %}{% if request.META.HTTP_REFERER %}{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}{% else %}/{% endif %}{% endif %}" name="next" />
```

Here are the cases it addresses:

1. If the **user comes from a login_required view**: next is set by login_required
2. If the **user comes from the login form** (ie. authentication did not pass): next=the previously set next value
3. If the **user comes from a non login_required view**: next=the referer url
4. If the **user directly opened the login page**: next=/

Note that this works with external login views too, which you should use.

As a goodie, here is part of my logout template, that redirects the user to the page he was before logging out.

```
{% block body %}
    <p>{% trans "You've been logged out." %}</p>
    {% if '/account/logout/' not in request.META.HTTP_REFERER %}
    <p>
        {% trans 'You will be redirected in a second' %}
    </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_body %}
    {% if '/account/logout/' not in request.META.HTTP_REFERER %}
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.location.href = '{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}';
        </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I would like to thank the great startup that hired me [sports pick, tipster social network](http://betspire.com) because they allow me to 0) share the code and 1) use some of my time to help others. But the real reason I link it is so that you can test it. If this code doesn't work for you like it works there then you have another problem.

Comment: Same question: what's the point of reinventing [the wheel](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L25)?

Comment: I guess the educational purpose is reasonable. Personally, I haven't done anything related to a login view for years, been too busy focusing on what makes my app different ... thanks to Pinax for providing starter projects that include all this boilerplate. But before, I did work on that manually and that helped me understand what's going on.

Comment: I think, studying the code of built-in view is much more useful for educational purposes. For example one can learn about test cookies and redirect security checks.

Comment: @jpic i have added your code to form template. it says "Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'me' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."

Comment: @DrTyrsa: thanks for your feedback, in the end i agree with you and pasted a solution a actually have implemented. It's simple and stupid, and relies on having a template and a classic "next" parameter support. The answer is IMHO, much better now, thanks for sharing some of your insight.

Comment: @ChamingaD yep i corrected it as soon as i noticed it. Thanks for your feedback, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @jpic now "<input type="hidden" value="{% if request.REQUEST.next %}{{ request.REQUEST.next }}{% else %}{% if request.META.HTTP_REFERER %}{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}{% else %}/{% endif %}{% endif %}" name="next" />" is fine. but i does not redirect to the page in `next`. It just redirect to root after login

Comment: @jpic But why? Django does it all. `login_required` decorator appends `?next` to url. `login` view redirects to `next`. It all exists. No work required. And your solution solves different task, and isn't always suitable. What if I have `login_required` decorator on my `HTTP_REFERER` view? I just want to logout, but the site invites me to login back, right?

Comment: @jpic Hmm. Let me clear my issue again ;) I have link named `Quiz`. It's view forced to login using `@login_required(login_url='/login/')`. So when i goto `Quiz` page it will redirect to `Login` if i haven't. In the query string it passes `?next=/quiz/`. What i was trying to read that query as GET parameter and redirect to it after successful login.

Comment: @jpic BTW, what about turning off DEBUG mode at your site. And please, install markdown library. ;-)

Comment: @DrTyrsa why can't i read GET parameter and redirect to it ? :/

Comment: @ChamingaD Once again: use built-in view and save your time.

Comment: "But why? Django does it all. login_required decorator appends ?next to url. login view redirects to next. It all exists. No work required. " -> because the user can also click on the link "login" from a non login_required page, and in that case "next" will **not** be set, i've updated the answer to add this detail, is it clear now ? Thanks for your feedback (markdown didn't convince the PM, although i'm personally fond of this kind of stuff, RST, markdown, textile, creole ...).

Comment: @ChamingaD as you can see in the code you posted in your comment, the first value that is tried for next is request.REQUEST.next. So if that doesn't work for you, then maybe it's time to get rid of your login view. It is easy to check that it works, see this url: http://betspire.com/fr/account/login/?next=/misc/leaderboard/month/ works as expected.

Comment: Its not working for https when I am trying this with my code its working for http, but when trying with https then not redirecting its just stuck there. Can you please tell me how to do the same for https

Comment: You should open a new question with your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask