# How to add Login/Logout link (Django)

Tags: python, django

I need a link in django template which turns into logout if user is authenticated. (i have already implemented login/logout pages)

tried `{% if user.is_authenticated %} {% endif %}` and `{% if user.is_anonymous %} {% endif %}` but didn't work.

Test Code (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) -

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Returns **false** evan after logged in successfully.

Comment: @Blender yes, tried using with that also.

Comment: Then you're coding something wrong. Post your template code.

Comment: That should work. Is `user.is_authenticated` set correctly, or is it always `True`?

Comment: @Blender that's test code i taken from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ (not for login/logout)

Comment: @Blender what you mean by set correctly ? `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` always returns false.

Comment: use request.user; furthermore, according your post question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989149/redirect-back-to-previous-page-after-logged-in-django , you may not login correctly

Comment: @okm no, login works fine. do i have to add anything to settings to make `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is anything wrong with the template code you posted. So I'd check out the associated view. In particular, if you're using a custom-made view (rather than, say, a generic view), remember to supply a [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) to your template.

From the [Django tutorial, part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial04/):

```
from django.template import RequestContext
# ...
def detail(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {'poll': p},
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks :) It worked by adding `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`